# How to efficiently propagate back a complete stack trace while retyping the exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a simplified example:

```
class FooException(Exception): pass
class BarException(Exception): pass

def subprocess_one():
  # make lots of calls to external service Foo that might fail in all weird ways
  pass

def subprocess_two():
  # make lots of calls to external service Bar that might fail in all weird ways
  raise RuntimeError('hello world')
def api_call():
  try:
    subprocess_one()
  except Exception as e:
    raise FooException(e) from e
  try:
    print('woops')
    subprocess_two()
  except Exception as e:
    print('raising barexception')
    raise BarException(e) from e

api_call()
```

[This raises the following stack trace](https://repl.it/KY7d/0):

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

woops
raising barexception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 23, in <module>
  File "python", line 21, in api_call
BarException: hello world
```

What I would like to see is something more along the lines of:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 23, in <module>
  File "python", line 21, in api_call
  File "python", line 9, in subprocess_call
BarException: hello world
```

or somehow to otherwise clearly show the historical trace generated by the wrapped exception (note the addition of the originating line and function as part of the traceback).

My assumption was that the `raise BarException(e) from e` approach would do this, but, it does not seem to do so. Short of printing the stack from exc_info is there a way to do this?

I am using Python 3.5+ so I'm less interested in a Python 2.7 solution.

Comment: I think this may be a problem with repl.it.  If I run the code with Python 3.5 on my computer (both in a file and in the REPL), I get the RuntimeError's traceback, the line "The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:", and the BarException's traceback.

Comment: @jwodder (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻. That's what I get for prototyping there... will teach me to not make an MVCE! Hah!